# Number of key comparisons for best case in MergeSort

Tags: arrays, sorting, mergesort

I am really confused about how to calculate the number of key comparisons for best case in MergeSort. Assume that the array input size is a, where a=2^k

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the array size is a power of 2, all merge phases involve slices of equal sizes, all powers of 2. The minimum number of comparisons for a pair of slices of length *p* is *p*, for example if the array is already sorted.

Hence the total number of comparisons for different power of 2:

- a=1 -> 0 comparison
- a=2 -> 1 comparison
- a=4 -> 2*1+2 = 4 comparisons
- a=8 -> 2*4+4 = 12 comparisons
- a=16 -> 2*12+8 = 32 comparisons
- a=32 -> 2*32+16 = 80 comparisons
- a=2<sup>k</sup> -> k * 2<sup>k-1</sup> comparisons
- a=2<sup>k+1</sup> -> 2 * k * 2<sup>k-1</sup> + 2<sup>k</sup> -> (k+1) * 2<sup>k</sup> comparisons (QED)

In the best case, merge sort will perform k * 2<sup>k-1</sup> comparisons for an array of length 2<sup>k</sup>.